# Kibana Historgram calculate profit/gross margin based on field values

Tags: groovy, lucene, elasticsearch, histogram, kibana

I'm trying to calculate the average profitmargin on the fly using histogram based on time/category/vendor etc in Kibana. The database has no calculated margins from the start
(see index below).

I need to calculate the profit margin by `(Netvalue - Cost)/NetValue * 100` and show the result in the the histogram.

Is it possible to make a groovy function or similar to [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/script-score.html) but using the result in a histogram?

Been trying for days to get something working but I just can't figure out which way to go or even if it's possible to do it in kibana on query level.

```
{
    "Mycompany": {
        "mappings": {
            "sales": {
                "properties": {
                    "Cost": {
                        "type": "double"
                    },
                    "DocumentDate": {
                        "format": "dateOptionalTime",
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "ItemCategory": {
                        "index": "not_analyzed",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "ManufacturerName": {
                        "index": "not_analyzed",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "MaterialGroup2description": {
                        "index": "not_analyzed",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "MaterialGroup4description": {
                        "index": "not_analyzed",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "NetPrice": {
                        "type": "double"
                    },
                    "NetValue": {
                        "type": "double"
                    },
                    "OrderQuantity": {
                        "type": "long"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: According to me it's a bit unclear what You want to achieve. Give some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Kibana 4 introduced Scripted fields that can be used in Histograms and such

[enter link description here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/kibana-4-beta-3-now-more-filtery/)